# Pagenavi with archive page

Tags: wp-query, pagination, plugin-wp-pagenavi

I have some problems in making wp_pagenavi works. I have a custom post archive page in which I activated the function. Here's the code:

```
<?php 

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'connazionali' ),
    'nopaging'               => false,
    'paged'                  => '1',

);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
    }
wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ));
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

The pagination displays correctly but when I click on second page, the same three articles are displayed (even if the url /page/2 is correct). I noticed this problem only on archive page, while on category page it is working fine.

Ho can I solve the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It always displays the first page because you *tell* it to: `'paged' => '1'` :)

That said [changing main query and especially pagination inside a template is inherently unreliable](https://www.rarst.net/wordpress/query-posts-breaks-pagination/).

For proper customization of such you should always be adjusting main query before template is ever reached via appropriate hooks, typically `pre_get_posts`.